# Прайвет-роомс, Private Rooms, privat rums, Приват Румс, - как это будет по-русски?

Tags: переводы

> Помимо нескольких неплохих ресторанов, и кинотеатра, где проходит
>   фестиваль американского кино, отель владеет театром (точным ремейком
>   Версальского), где идут театрализованные шоу, и собственно казино, в
>   котором проходят игры с серьезными ставками, а в прайвет-роомс
>   — чемпионаты мира по бриджу.

Я понимаю, что приватные (для неофициального общения) комнаты или помещения слишком громоздко;

вариант написания из моей цитаты - ни в какие ворота,

но почему-то ужасно хочется изобразить дефисное написание:

ПРАЙВЕТ-РУМС или ПРИВАТ-РУМС...

Разуверьте меня, если что, если есть узаконенный прецедент.

Comment: Эти private rooms тоже находятся в казино или нет?

Comment: Ну да, чёрным по жёлтому ж: *...казино, в котором проходят игры с серьезными ставками, а в прайвет-роомс — чемпионаты мира по бриджу*. Отель владеет чем? - театром и казино. Самое то для бриджа.

Comment: Не знаю, я бы перевёл, если это возможно. По крайней мере, если бы придумал неплохой вариант. В Мультитране кто-то предложил вариант "отдельный кабинет", а кто-то — просто "кабинет" с припиской "в ресторане". Наверняка, так же и в казино. Но всё равно выходит не очень. Рискну предложить один вариант в ответе. Если раскритикуете, удалю.)) Но мне нравится.)))

Comment: Рискни. Не понравится - удали. А если я оценку за риск поставлю, она тоже удалится, вместе с ответом?

Comment: Ага, удалится, так всегда.

Comment: Так не удаляй. Ты ж не рениксу какую скажешь, а вариантом поделишься...

Comment: "Реникса"! Даже и не знал такого! Спасибо за новое словечко!) А я удивился, почему Вы того ответившего рениксом называете))) А потом перечитал, понял, что не понимаю смысла, а после этого уже дошло, что есть такое слово "реникса"!)))))

Comment: Нашёл? Автор - Антон Палыч.

Comment: Аж так! Прочитал только, что русское слово прочитали латиницей, а дальше не продолжил.( Теперь дочитал. Только всё равно не понял, как с произведением "Три сестры" связано... Поиском посмотрел по нему — там такого нету.

Comment: *Кулыгин. В какой-то семинарии учитель написал на сочинении «чепуха», а ученик прочел «реникса» – думал, по-латыни написано. (Смеется.) Смешно удивительно. Говорят, Соленый влюблен в Ирину и будто возненавидел барона… Это понятно. Ирина очень хорошая девушка. Она даже похожа на Машу, такая же задумчивая. Только у тебя, Ирина, характер мягче. Хотя и у Маши, впрочем, тоже очень хороший характер. Я ее люблю, Машу*.

А. П. Чехов, «Три сестры», 1900 г.

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается, у меня только первое действие открылось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, "слишком громоздко" - не основание брать и вставлять иностранное слово. Например, на русский язык слово *challenger* в некоторых контекстах не может быть переведено иначе, чем "человек, бросающий вызов". Получается, вы бы просто "челленджер" написали?

Безусловно, "роомс" выглядит убого. Но тут надо просто знать, есть ли традиция называть *роомсами* специальные комнаты для бриджа, чтобы не путать их с румсами для всего остального. Если такой традиции нет, то "прайвет-румс", раз так хочется оригинального звучания.

Answer (score 2):

Как Вам такой вариант, Галина?

> ...а в специально отведённых под это комнатах — чемпионаты мира по бриджу.

Мне кажется, что по смыслу именно это имеется в виду. Комнаты, действительно, частные, личные, игроки, возможно, и правда изолируются от остальных людей. Проследить за ними даже при желании может быть невозможно. Но так ли важно подчеркнуть это в тексте? Мне кажется, секретность в моей формулировке не гарантируется, но невольно формируется именно такое представление.

Comment: Спасибо за правку! Ставить эту запятую очень не хотелось, но показалось, что это вводное слово и что формально она должна быть.

Comment: Так как Вам мои мысли-то и вариант? Что думаете?

Comment: Думаю, что ты как-то не приметил, что все мои вопросы по этому автору изобилуют транслитерациями. Автор давно живёт в европах и сознательно не затрудняется искать русские эквиваленты.

Comment: То есть это значит, что, хорошо это или плохо, но нельзя искажать его стиль и передавать по-русски то, что он не хотел переводить?

Comment: Стиль - ни в коем случае, ошибки - непременно. Вот я предложила свои дефисные варианты... Кто-то может сослаться на обнаруженные прецеденты.

Comment: В знаменитой своей книжке Нора Галь сравнивала переводы, так же изобилующие транслитерациями, как и этот, с теми, что были сделаны после, с прекрасными находками, как передать всё то же по-русски. Всем понятно, в пользу каких было сравнение. Вот мне и кажется поэтому, что все эти дёрганья от одного иноязычного варианта к другому — это тупиковый путь. Если бы я вынужден был этим заниматься, на меня бы напала жуткая тоска.

Comment: Тёмыч, приглашу тебя на открытие сайта; посмотришь, каким он станет, когда всё будет вылизано.

Comment: А какого сайта?

Comment: Интернет-ресурса, с шикарррными картинками и красивыми буквами; к Новому году торопимся, но это пока первая корректура - снимаем поверхностную грязь. Дорогих денег автору будет стоить.

Comment: Посмотрю, интересно, спасибо)